# Why does dput(object) in j in data.table also print(object)?

Tags: r, data.table, output

Not high priority, but this is an operation I carry out frequently. So, I'd like to know if there's any way to suppress the output of the expression inside `dput`.

```
library(data.table)
mtcars <- setDT(copy(mtcars))
mtcars[, dput(unique(gear))]
# c(4, 3, 5) <---- **only** this line was the expected output
# [1] 4 3 5 <---- Why is this line also returned?
dput(unique(mtcars$gear))
# c(4, 3, 5) <---- Expected output
```

I know `dput(unique(mtcars$gear))` works, so not sure why it doesn't work as expected in `j`.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You asked `dput` to output the (vector of) unique values of `mtcars$gear`, so that's exactly what it did. What exactly do you want to have output? Are you perhaps trying to group-by `gear`, then output something else? Like `mtcars[..., dput(something_else?), by=gear]`

Comment: @smci The output contains two lines (commented out above in the question). I was expecting **only** the first line. The second line seemed unnecessary.

Comment: Edited title to *"display both the unevaluated and evaluated expression?"*

Comment: `mtcars[, dput(unique(gear))]` yields the output of `dput(unique(gear))` **and** `unique(gear)`. I was expecting only the output of the former expression. Is that what you meant by evaluated and unevaluated?

Comment: Yes I think those are both the unevaluated and evaluated dput expressions? (If not, whenever you figure out what the second line is, please edit the title)

Comment: Regarding "any way to suppress the output of the expression inside `dput`", yes, `dput(mtcars[, unique(gear)])` or `invisible(mtcars[, dput(unique(gear))])` or `with(mtcars, dput(unique(gear)))` or with the magrittr package, `mtcars[, unique(gear)] %>% dput`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From dput() documentation:
*dput: Writes an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file or connection, or uses one to recreate the object.*. And for the output of the function: "*For dput, the first argument invisibly*"

The first line in the output is dput() printing to the screen and the second is what returned by using the output of the function for sub-setting. You will see a similar behavior from `deparse()` except `deparse()` does not output anything to the screen, so there will be no first line:

```
mtcars[, deparse(unique(mtcars$gear))]
#[1] "c(4, 3, 5)"
```

A better example of  dput() behavior is to use print() function :

```
print(dput(unique(mtcars$gear)))
#c(4, 3, 5)   # this line is what dput() prints to the screen
#[1] 4 3 5    # this line comes as a result of print the return value of dput()
```

If you add a file name to `dput()` function, you will see that the first line no longer printed and only second one (the return value of `dput()` is printed to the screen:

```
print(dput(unique(mtcars$gear), file="xxx.txt"))
# [1] 4 3 5
```

It might be easier to understand how it works on the following example:

```
# Define a function that prints a message and returns the object using invisible() function (which suppress the output)
my.f <- function(x) {message(x); invisible(x)}

# This will print the message, but will not print the output of the function
my.f(777)
# 777  

# This will print the message and force printing the return value
print(my.f(777))
# 777
# [1] 777
```

`dput()` works in a similar way except instead of using message() function it either prints the content to the file (if the name provided) or sends the print statement to the standard output.

Comment: But I indeed am looking for the `dput` output. Just not the output of the expression inside it. In this case, `dput(unique(mtcars$gear))` is what I am looking for.

Comment: OK. But what would you like to see for subsetting . Do you want to output 3rd, 4th and 5th column?

Comment: I'm not looking to output any columns, I want to know how many unique values there are in a given column, and to recreate a vector of those unique values. In this case, `c(4, 3, 5)`

Comment: Then length(unique(mtcars$gear)) will give you the number of unique values and unique(mtcars$gear) will give you the vector itself. dput() function is used to write the output to a standard output or file. It is not necessary here.

Comment: That explains it. However, it still doesn't make sense to `print` the output instead of just returning the output as one may expect.

Comment: "the second is what returned by using the output of the function for sub-setting" -- it's not really subsetting, just evaluating. I think it's because `j` doesn't play nice with invisible output: `mtcars[, invisible(42)]` and `(invisible(42))` and `invisible(42)[]` similarly print. Also, fwiw, I would quote the "Value" section of the dput docs.